# I can't connect my express rest api to mongo db atlas, using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, rest

Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

Things I've tried:

- Whitelisting all IP addresses under security, inside of my mongo db atlas, by setting a catchall IP address: 0.0.0.0/0
- Whitelisting my specific IP address
- Changing my password, and making is super insecure and adding it directly to the uri string, to make sure that it's not a credentials issue.
- Commenting all other lines of code to test the uri string only.
- Using the default port number 3000

My Index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// CORE MIDDLEWARE
app.use(express.static('public'));

// CUSTOM MIDDLEWARE
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// MONGO/MONGOOSE



mongoose.connect
(`mongodb+srv://myUsername:MyPassword@ClusterName.id9lz.mongodb.net/database- 
 name?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
 })

 const port = 5000 || process.env.PORT;

 app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to port ${port}...`)
 })
```

NOTE: I've cut out all excess code like dependencies, etc, out of this question, so it's easier to parse through and find an answer faster. I'm completely out of ideas. I don't know what else to even attempt. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you trying to connect with the root/main atlas user?. Try creating a new user who only have the permission you need. This happened to me once.

Comment: Didn't work. I'm completely out of ideas right now

Comment: Hi again, after reading and review you code again, i thing the problem may be that you're not handle the promise that function returns, try what @Diego post in the answer below

Comment: I already tried enclosing it in a promise. I didn't need to do that before but, even doing that, the problem still persists. I'm starting to think that maybe there was a recent change to atlas, and that I need to do something new, because nothing is working

Comment: In the URI string, at the end, try deleting the last options `?retryWrites=true&w=majority`. I always connect without those options and works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before, i don't know why really, but, after 2 hours, it started to work correctly again, the only thing that comes to my mind is that my internet was kinda weak... But i really don't know why was that happening anyways.

But, you should try to change the way you want to connect your server to mongoDB, i used to do it like that, but after a while, i've had some problems.

So, try to change it like this

```
const port = 5000 || process.env.PORT;

mongoose.connect
(`mongodb+srv://myUsername:MyPassword@ClusterName.id9lz.mongodb.net/database- 
 name?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
 }).then(() => {

 app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to port ${port}...`)
 })

console.log('MongoDB connected correctly')

})
```

And also, make sure you're credentials are correct while trying to connect to MongoDB

Hope i helped you a litle bit !